# Простой http сервер повисает на считывании из потока

Tags: java, сервер, http, сокет

Пытаюсь написать простой http server на Java. Через браузер подключается, и повисает на чтении строки из потока.
Работает, только если Socet будет создаваться в цикле. И вот здесь я ни как не могу разобраться почему.

```
public class SimpleServer {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket socket;
private static InputStream in;
private static OutputStream out;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80, 1, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Wait for TCP-connection...");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted\n");

            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();

            readInputHeaders(in);
            transferData(out);

            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void readInputHeaders(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    while (true) {
        String s = br.readLine();
        if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static void transferData(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:/SomeFolder/htmlPage.html");
    byte[] buff = new byte[4096];

    while (fis.available() > 0) {
        fis.read(buff);
        out.write(buff);
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

}

Comment: Что Вы посылаете на сервер?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Через браузер открываю localhost, браузер запрашивает данные, и отравляет на сервер GET запросы

Comment: Попробуйте протестить простым же клиентом на джаве. `readLine` читает строку, поэтому он ждет символа окончания строки. Скорее всего в Вашем запросе такого символа нет.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Обычным клиентом на java работает. Про окончание строки тоже думал, что и-за этого скорее всего. Но все же хочу разобраться как тогда нужно делать чтобы с браузером нормально заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем дело в том, что Вы не отправляете ответ. Я запустил код и немного подебажил его. сделал `GET localhost` из браузера.

В моем случае, все заголовки отобразились в консоли. Но из-за этого цикла:

```java
while (true) {
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    readInputHeaders(in);
}
```

сервер вернулся обратно, снова ожидая увидеть заголовки. В запросе больше ничего нет, поэтому в сокет больше ничего не пишется. В то же время, соединение не закрывается клиентом, потому что браузер ожидает увидеть HTTP-response.

Из-за того что, браузер не закрывает сокет и не пишет туда ничего `readLine()` и висит.

Поэтому, Вам следует добавить логики в свой код. Определить есть ли боди, и если есть, продолжить его читать. Когда все прочитано, нужно ответить браузеру в соотв-ие с протоколом HTTP. Тогда браузер закроет соединение, сокет разорвется.

Comment: Исправил и доработал код, но вот вопрос, правильно ли что сокет создается в цикле? Так я жду новых запросов от браузера.

Comment: В идеале, должен быть класс, куда вынесена логика обработки клиентских запросов. Сокет может создаваться в цикле, но при создании, должен создаваться новый поток, куда будет передаваться созданный сокет. Пул таких параллельных хендлеров должен быть ограничен и новый сокет не должен создаваться пока в этом пуле нет свободных мест.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо, буду дальше про это подробнее читать!